# Definition of zero checking expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

Let

$T\equiv\lambda xy.x$
$F\equiv\lambda xy.y$

Numbers are represented as:

$0\equiv\lambda sz.z$
$1\equiv\lambda sz.s(z)$
$2\equiv\lambda sz.s(s(z))$
$N\equiv\lambda sz.\underbrace{s(s( ... (s(}_\text{N times}z))...))$

I want to define zero checking expression $Z$, being applied to $0$ reduces to $T$, otherwise $F$.

$Z\equiv\lambda f.f(\lambda t.F)T$

$Z0\equiv(\lambda f.f(\lambda t.F)T)(\lambda sz.z)=(\lambda sz.z)(\lambda t.F)T=T$
$ZN\equiv(\lambda f.f(\lambda t.F)T)(\lambda sz.\underbrace{s(s( ... (s(}_\text{N times}z))...)))=(\lambda sz.\underbrace{s(s( ... (s(}_\text{N times}z))...)))(\lambda t.F)T=\underbrace{(\lambda t.F)((\lambda t.F)( ... ((\lambda t.F)(}_\text{N times}T))...)))=F$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Seems fine to me. You should be more self-confident. Try to *prove* that your solution is correct.

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].